# Attaching CKEditor in ajax page

Tags: php, ajax, ckeditor

I was try to attach the *ckeditor* to a textarea in php page, which is being called by ajax in a html page, but ckeditor is not appearing in textarea. Can any one have any idea, Why it is not happening, it just making me freak.

TRY1.HTML

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function load()
    {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
   else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
             document.getElementById("div_content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
      }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","try2.php?",true);
       xmlhttp.send();
      }
     </script>
     <!--end tinymcs-->

       </head>
       <body>
       <input type="button" onclick="load()">
       <div id="div_content">

       </div>


       </body>
       </html>
```

TRY2.PHP

```
      <textarea id="txt1"> </textarea>
```

Comment: Is the textarea getting on the page as a result of ajax call response?

Comment: Yes the initial page is home.html whoose middle portion contains a blank div by using ajax i'm loading a php page named add_content.php inside that div.And the text area is in that php page.

Comment: Check my answer,I have posted some code in it and it is likely to work in your case.

Comment: Let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the textarea in which you are binding the editor was not present on the initial load of the page so its not getting binded.
You should bind that on the success call back of ajax call.
On Success you should do bind the textarea with ckeditor and it will work.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("div_content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("txt1").ckEditor();
    //or whatever the exact code you do for ckEditor
}
```

Comment: Thankz now can you please tell me how to bind that text area in success call back of ajax,that will be really help fi\ull for me..

Comment: Post your code for me,Just edit the question and add the code in it.

Comment: <html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("div_content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","try2.php?",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<!--end tinymcs-->

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="load()">
<div id="div_content">

</div>

</iframe>
</body>
</html>

Comment: <textarea id="txt1"> </textarea>

Comment: THE 1ST ONE IS MY HOME PAGE WHERE ON A CLIK EVENT ON BUTTON TRY2.PHP WILL APPER WHICH IS THE 2ND